# Debug JavaScript in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, intellij-idea, google-chrome-extension

How can I debug JavaScript for my website in IntelliJ IDEA without changing my build configuration?

I am able to debug the JavaScript in Chrome Console but it does not work very well.

---

Answer. It is really easy:

[image: Answer]

Comment: what instructions you refer to? Normally changing build configuration is not required (unless it doesn't allow code debugging - no valid sourcemaps produced, etc.). I can hardly advise on setting up the debugger unless you provide a project I can play with

Comment: This project uses WAMP server.I think It will look like I am trying to debug foreign site. Can I do it? Can I connect a debugger to any web site in chrome?

Comment: sure - ust specify the URL of your app on WAMP in **JavaScript Debug** run configuration

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I can not find this in settings... Can you write a path or make a screenshot? 

Of course, I tried to find a solution on the Internet but all they were very hard or unresolved for WAMP server.

Comment: what settings? Just create a new *JavaScript Debug* run configuration and specify the address you normally use to open your application in browser as URL there. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html#d45520e154 and linked topics

Comment: Oh.. so easy... Can you write the answer? Then I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) **Run configuration** and specify the WAMP address you normally use to open your application in browser as **URL** there. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html#d45520e154 and linked topics.
You might also need to configure URL mappings in your configuration - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/debugging-javascript-deployed-to-a-remote-server.html#d46122e202

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add intellij plugin for chrom and install it on chrom, then on configuration debug
 you need to choose run with javascript.
I can show you screenshot if you want

Comment: You should just go ahead and add the screenshot ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that you should have linked separate .js files for debugging. I was trying to debug JavaScript code which was within an .html file but the breakpoints were never hit. I looked later under the resources in Chrome Inspector and found out that the lines were not synchronized between the files, because for the debugger the first line was the first JavaScript line, but for the html file it was the first line of the file (DOCTYPE)